Endomorphisms of $\mathbb{C}^2$ as an associative unital $\mathbb{C}$-algebra
Given a commutative unital ring $R$ and associative unital $R$-algebras $A$ and $B$, call a map $\varphi: A \to B$ a morphism of associative unital $R$-algebras if it satisfies the following conditions:

$\forall a_1, a_2 \in A: \varphi(a_1 + a_2) = \varphi(a_1) + \varphi(a_2)$

$\forall a \in A, r \in R: \varphi(r \cdot a) = r \cdot \varphi(a)$

$\forall a_1, a_2 \in A: \varphi(a_1 \cdot a_2) = \varphi(a_1) \cdot \varphi(a_2)$

$\varphi(1) = 1$


Consider $\mathbb{C}^2$ as an associative unital $\mathbb{C}$-algebra. Is it correct that the only endomorphisms $\varphi: \mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{C}^2$ are the ones represented by the following matrices?
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ \end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \\ \end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix}
$$

So you mean to consider the $\mathbb{C}^2$ as the product algebra of two copies of $\mathbb{C}$. Algebra endomorphisms $\mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{C}^2$ would therefore be in natural bijection with pairs of algebra maps $\mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{C}$. So let's analyze algebra maps $f: \mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{C}$. They are uniquely determined by what they do to the idempotents $e_1 = (1, 0)$ and $e_2 = (0, 1)$. Since $f$ is a ring map,  $f(e_1)$ and $f(e_2)$ are forced to be be idempotent (so, either $0$ or $1$), and $f(e_1) + f(e_2) = 1$, and $f(e_1)f(e_2) = 0$. The only two possibilities are either $f(e_1) = 1$ and $f(e_2) = 0$, or $f(e_1) = 0$ and $f(e_2) = 1$. The $1 \times 2$ matrices representing these possibilities are $(1, 0)$ and $(0, 1)$. The pairs of such matrices fill out the rows of the matrices you are after, so your description is correct.
